# Replicate_Do_DB and Replicate_Wild_Do_Table - Replication does not work

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have been tasked to set replication up on a slave host. The master database is a "data store" where tables are dropped, recreated, and reloaded on a daily basis.

My initial setup of the slave host worked fine by replication was always days behind the master. After talking to the users of the "data store", I realized that not all of the databases and not all of the tables need to be replicated over. So this is what I did

```
CI-DB002-PRD [root@localhost] ON (none)>  STOP SLAVE\G

CI-DB002-PRD [root@localhost] ON (none)> CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_DO_DB = (bidw,cf2_fact,ct_fact,ez_fact,gt_fact,sfdc,soa_fact,tesla_fact,tmc_fact);

CI-DB002-PRD [root@localhost] ON (none)> CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER REPLICATE_WILD_DO_TABLE = ('bidw.domo%', 'bidw.consolidated%', 'bidw.cf2%', 'bidw.tesla%');

CI-DB002-PRD [root@localhost] ON (none)>  START SLAVE\G
```

Very quickly, replication caught up and now, the slave is 3-7 seconds behind the master.

But replication is not touching the databases I want to be replicated. Even though data changes on master every 10 minutes for the schemas I list above. I did several validation queries and results now differ. When I check the status of my slave, nothing stands out

```
CI-DB002-PRD [root@localhost] ON (none)> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log
                  Master_Host: 10.239.0.34
                  Master_User: ci02replicadb
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: binary-log.009871
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 14678596
               Relay_Log_File: ci-db002-prd-relay-bin.007914
                Relay_Log_Pos: 814824
        Relay_Master_Log_File: binary-log.009871
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: bidw,cf2_fact,ct_fact,ez_fact,gt_fact,sfdc,soa_fact,tesla_fact,tmc_fact,staging,phoenix,data_science
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: bidw.domo%,bidw.consolidated%,bidw.cf2%,bidw.tesla%,bidw.ez%,bidw.ct%,bidw.gt%,bidw.tmc%,bidw.did%,bidw.Shortened%,bidw.other_revenue%,bidw.revenue%,bidw.advanced_cohort%
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 814626
              Relay_Log_Space: 14679056
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 22
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: a485ab14-aa57-11ea-bef5-42010aef0022
             Master_Info_File: /data/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

For "Replicate_Wild_Do_Table", I replicate only the tables listed there because the entire "bidw" database is lousy with junk tables.

What am I missing here? Am I not allowed to use both filters at the same time? I am on version 5.7.31.

Answer (score 0):

(dba.stackexchange.com is probably a better place to ask.)

Some things to try:

- Can you move the do_db filtering to the Primary as "binlog_do_db"?  If so, this will also improve performance since the Replica won't be pulling the stuff, then tossing it.
- Move the `replicate_do_db` into the `Replicate_Wild_Do_Table` list.  (When mixing the various `replicate...` options, strange things can happen.)